# Cannot be root from a tmux session on a remote machine

Tags: shell, sudo, tmux

I can become root when I am logged into a gateway node, but not when I have my tmux session running. I can ssh into other machines and become root but the not the one running the tmux. This issue seems to be isolated to our gateway node in production.

In tmux

```
user@gateway:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for user:
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

No tmux

```
user@gateway:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for user:
root@gateway:/home/user#
```

Answer (score 3):

I had unattached tmux sessions that needed to be closed.